# Node Exports from App.js

Tags: node.js, express, export

I am using the express framework and I am trying to export more than just my "app" from my app.js file. However, I don't seem to be able to access my methods / objects from my functions.js file. Is it possible to export more than just your app from app.js?

Here is the relevant code.

app.js

```
var test = "test";
//exports - trying to export serialPort so can play with it. 
module.exports = ({
  toArdu:toArdu(),
  serialPort:serialPort,
  test:test,
  app:app
});
```

functions.js

```
app_page = require('./app.js')
app = app_page.app;
toArdu = app_page.toArdu;
test = app_page.test;
serialPort = app_page.serialPort;

console.log("serialPort : " + serialPort);
console.log("this is functions :" + toArdu);
console.log("test " + test);
```

Thanks in advance.

Sorry, when I look at my console:

```
this is functions :undefined
serialPort : undefined
test : undefined
```

Comment: where did `jim` come from?

Comment: sorry. old output where I had jim in there. will edit now

Comment: The code you show in your question actually won't run due to undefined symbols. Please put in your question runnable code that accurately reproduces the problem. One of your issues is that you seem to expect the exported `toArdu` to be a function but you initialize it to `toArdu()` inside the module. I'd expect `toArdu: toArdu`, like you have `test: test`.

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
var test = "test";
//exports - trying to export serialPort so can play with it. 
module.exports = ({
  toArdu:toArdu(),
  serialPort:serialPort(),
  test:test,
  app:"My app"
});

function toArdu(){
    return true;
}
function serialPort(){
    return false;
}
```

functions.js

```
app_page = require('./app.js')
console.log("this is functions :" + app_page.toArdu);
console.log("serialPort : " + app_page.serialPort);
console.log("test " + app_page.test);
console.log("app " + app_page.app);
```

output:

```
this is functions :true
serialPort : false
test test
app My App
```

This works for me run with "node functions.js"

Comment: Thanks. I am using the automatically generated express framework. I.e. when you cd into the folder and type 'express' in a command prompt. I start the app with "npm start". I am able to export and require between other files without issues, however I think there might be something that I don't understand about the architecture of the express framework that is preventing me from exporting from my main app.js